# SQL Server 2008 - Modificar la opcion: "Modificar las primeras x filas"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimados, quisiera saber si puedo editar la opción que aparece al hacer clic derecho sobre una tabla de una base de datos en sql server 2008 "Editar las primeras 'x' filas".

Lo que quisiera modificar es que me muestre las filas ordenadas por uno de los campos que yo escoja de mayor a menor.

Es posible?

Comment: Dudo que puedas hacerlo, el  `"Editar las primeras 'x' filas"` es una acción genérica para cualquier tabla, tal vez se pueda modificar el valor de `x`, (lo desconozco) pero seguramente no debería permitirte modificar el `SELECT` default para agregar el orden a un determinado campo, si fuera así, funcionaría en una tabla y dejaría de hacerlo en todas las demás.

Comment: Como bien dice @PatricioMoracho no es posible. Lo que sí es posible es dar clic en la opción `Editar las primeras 'x' filas`, luego, das clic derecho en cualquier parte que no sean los resultados, luego seleccionar `Panel` y luego, `SQL`. Con eso se abre la sentencia SQL que genera la edición, ahí sí puedes acomodar las columnas en el orden deseado para poder visualizarlas en el orden que gustes ;)

Answer (score -1):

Cuando editas una tabla aparece en la barra de herramientas un ícono de Mostrar Criterios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ordenar aplicando el criterio o filtro que necesites. Con el otro comando Mostrar Paneles SQL, puedes aumentar el limite de registros que por defecto es 200.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No confundir con el panel de diseño, estamos en el menú contextual editar las primeras 200 filas y aplicando criterios para filtrar datos. Podemos ver los paneles de manera combinada en el ejemplo, filtrando olas con Potencia mayor a cincuenta a una profundidad menor a 200 metros. En el panel intermedio el asistente traduce a lenguaje SQL y en el panel inferior aparecen los datos filtrados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso modificaría el modelo de datos, lo que el OP está requeriendo es poder personalizar la opción `Editar las primeras 'x' filas`. Con el cambio que sugieres no repercute en nada en la selección de X número de filas, pero sí afecta en cómo está construída la tabla, es decir, su estructura.

Comment: La edición es para modificar un registro, ordenar u eliminar. No afecta al diseño de la tabla.